# is it possible to move js code from page to static resource

Tags: javascript

I had used js to show user interaction logo when ever it will take time, and now i wanted to move js code to static resource,and from there i wanted to access js code-

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is common practice to put JavaScript code into Static Resource.
However, you should be aware that you will not be able to use Visualforce expressions after you move JS code into Static Resource