# Call Javascript function on visualforce page from static resource?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, static-resources

I have a static resource that contains an angular.js module. Now i want to call, in this static resource, a javascript function that is located in a Visualforce Page.

Is it possible to use the `Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction`?
If not, could one resolve this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its definitely doable .You will need to use window global object to resolve all merge fields and then use the object in your static resource .

Here is a simple hello world example

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Javascript Tips</title>
    <script>
        window.configSettings = {
            user:{
                id : '{!$User.Id}',
                firstName : '{!$User.FirstName}',
                lastName : '{!$User.LastName}',
                uiThemeDisplayed : '{!$User.uiThemeDisplayed}', 
            },
          remoteActions: {
                helloWorld : '{!$RemoteAction.TestController.helloWorld}',
            }
        }
    </script>
   <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.MyJavascriptFile)}"/>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div> ....</div>
</body>
```

apex class

```
public with sharing class TestController {  
 @ReadOnly    
 @RemoteAction    
 public static String helloWorld() { 
   return 'hello word' ;  
 } 
}
```

The Static Resource Script

```
(function (window) {     
  Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
  window.configSettings.helloWorld,
  function(result, event) {
    if (event.status) {
     console.log(result);
    } else {
      //handleReturnError(event);
    }
   },      
    {buffer: true, escape: true}
  );
})(window);
```

Comment: Excellent answer. for us non java folks this helps bridge a gap. Would make an excellent blog post.......

Comment: Ah nice, had wrote something [similar](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/152527/is-it-possible-to-move-js-code-from-page-to-static-resource/152533#152533), not better than yours though (still learning the best practices). With that it doesn't pollute window object directly.

Comment: @RahulSharma I loved the module pattern .Its great.The thing about Javascript is its changing so much .This is ES5 way of doing it .In ES6 we have classes and other ways to handle this polluting issues .